# Postgres select rows from a table using column names specified in another

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres 11.14
I have a table with a list of column names in it.

I want to create a function that

- executes a query that returns a result set containing a row with a column for each of the column names in the table.
- then loops through all of the columns in the table and returns a row containing the column name and the content of that column in the result set.

so for example.

column_table:

```
|column_name|
 |a|
 |b|
 |c|
```

Function pseudocode:

```
insert into record_set select z+y as a, b, x / w as c from another_table limit 1;

for column_name  in select column_name from column_table
  loop
    select into result column_name, record_set.column_name  -- recordset column with the name of the contents of the variable column_name
  end loop;
return result
```

I've tried several approaches, but have been unable to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that, is by using psql's feature `\gexec`:

```
bench=# with columns(names) as (
  select column_name
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_schema = 'public'
  and table_name = 'pgbench_accounts'
  order by ordinal_position asc 
  limit 3 
)
select 'select ' || string_agg(names, ',') || ' from pgbench_accounts limit 10' 
from columns
;
                        ?column?                        
--------------------------------------------------------
 select aid,bid,abalance from pgbench_accounts limit 10
(1 row)

bench=# with columns(names) as (
  select column_name
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_schema = 'public'
  and table_name = 'pgbench_accounts' 
  order by ordinal_position asc
  limit 3
) 
select 'select ' || string_agg(names, ',') || ' from pgbench_accounts limit 10'                                                                                                                                       from columns                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \gexec
 aid | bid | abalance 
-----+-----+----------
  13 |   1 |        0
  16 |   1 |        0
  33 |   1 |        0
  42 |   1 |        0
  49 |   1 |        0
  54 |   1 |        0
  55 |   1 |        0
  60 |   1 |     1722
  34 |   1 |     -867
   8 |   1 |     4394
(10 rows)

bench=#
```

Or you can use pl/pgsql (or any other language, regarding the extensions you installed, to perform dynamic SQL, but it feels like trying to kill a fly with a hammer).

Comment: hi - thanks.  It will be contained within a function, so pspgsql will be used.
I can't figure out the dynamic SQL

Comment: I think I'm not sure dynamic SQL is the right answer to your problem. From my experience, it's usually a bad idea (optimization fence and security flaws). You might be in the rare use case where it's really needed, but I really doubt it. So, could you maybe add more context to explain why you think a function is the only possible solution in your case?